# How do I sum up specific things in Numbers?

Tags: iwork, numbers

I have a spreadsheet in the newest iWork Numbers.app, with something like:

```
CATEGORY | POINTS  
      HW | 100
      HW | 100
      NW | 12
      HW | 50
      NW | 23
```

I want to just sum up all the `Category = HW` into a cell: I'm not sure how. I think I need to use the `SUMIF()` function but I get stuck afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct in that you need to use the SUMIF function.
This is the specification from the Function Browser:

```
SUMIF(test-values, condition, sum-values)
```

Try this in your cell:

```
=SUMIF(CATEGORY; "=HW"; POINTS)
```